# JaVers Diff Tool. Does PrettyPrint working?

Tags: javers

Build jb

```
JaversBuilder jb = JaversBuilder.javers().withMappingStyle(MappingStyle.BEAN).withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE).withPrettyPrint(true)
```

and then

```
log.info(diff.prettyPrint())
```

gives

```
1. ListChange{globalId:'fn.dsl.diff.javers.Instance/Folder:{0F1E2D3C-4B5A-6978-8796-A5B4C3D2E1F0}', property:'permissions', containerChanges:[(3).removed:'fn.dsl.diff.javers.Permission {type: 'ALLOW', mask: '135159', GN: 'entos_users_tst@tn.fntst.ru', GT: 'GROUP', source: 'DIRECT', depth: 'THIS_OBJECT_ONLY' }', (2).'fn.dsl.diff.javers.Permission {type: 'ALLOW', mask: '999415', GN: 'entos_admins_tst@tn.fntst.ru', GT: 'GROUP', source: 'DIRECT', depth: 'THIS_OBJECT_ONLY' }' to 'fn.dsl.diff.javers.Permission {type: 'ALLOW', mask: '135159', GN: 'entos_users_tst@tn.fntst.ru', GT: 'GROUP', source: 'DIRECT', depth: 'THIS_OBJECT_ONLY' }']}
```

, but expected pretty formatting. Like in docs - http://javers.org/documentation/diff-examples/#compare-valueobjects

```
System.out.println(diff);

//.. shouldDetectBossChange()

Diff:
1. ReferenceChange{
   globalId:'org.javers.core.examples.model.Employee/Great Developer',
   property:'boss',
   oldRef:'org.javers.core.examples.model.Employee/Manager One',
   newRef:'org.javers.core.examples.model.Employee/Manager Second'}
2. ListChange{
   globalId:'org.javers.core.examples.model.Employee/Manager Second',
   property:'subordinates',
   containerChanges: [(0).added:'org.javers.core.examples.model.Employee/Great Developer']}
3. ListChange{
   globalId:'org.javers.core.examples.model.Employee/Manager One',
   property:'subordinates',
   containerChanges:[(0).removed:'org.javers.core.examples.model.Employee/Great Developer']}
```

What am I do wrong? 
Should I expect pretty formatting as showed in docs or it was formatted manually?

Comment: For now I had to do it with regex   

`
    public static String prettyPrint(Diff diff) {
        String out = diff.prettyPrint()

        out = out.replaceAll("\\{globalId:","\\{\n\tglobalId:")
        out = out.replaceAll(", property:",",\n\tproperty:")
        out = out.replaceAll("\\((\\d)\\).","\n\t\t\\(\$1\\).")
        out = out.replaceAll("'>>'","'\n\t\t  >>'")

        return out
    }
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the doc you are referring to, line breaks was added manually.

`diff.toString()` and `diff.prettyPrint()` (as it's only the alias)
adds br after each change.
So even ListChange with a series of ElementChanges is printed in a single line.

Use [ChangeProcessor](http://javers.org/javadoc_2.0/org/javers/core/Javers.html#processChangeList-java.util.List-org.javers.core.changelog.ChangeProcessor-)
to customize your diff formatting. See [SimpleTextChangeLog](http://javers.org/javadoc_2.0/org/javers/core/changelog/SimpleTextChangeLog.html) example